# If a subset A of a Hilbert space H contains an Open ball, then the orthogonal complement of A is the set of zero element.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

> Question: If A contains an open ball then $A^{\perp}=\left \{ 0 \right \}$

Let A $\subseteq$ a Hilbert space H contains an open ball of size $\epsilon >0.$

Suppose $A^{\perp}=\left \{ v \in A : \left \langle v,a \right \rangle=0 ,\forall a \in A, \forall v \neq 0 \right \}$

Hints will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the most direct way to show it is to get that if the subspace has an open ball, then it also has an open ball around zero. From here follow that the subspace contains every element of the hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint (1):** $A^{\perp}= \textbf{Span}(A)^{\perp}$ and $\textbf{Span}(A)^{\perp} = \{0\} \iff \overline{(\textbf{Span}(A))}=  H$.

**Hint (2):**. Suppose $A^{\perp} \neq \{0\}$. There exists $v \neq 0 \in A^{\perp}$. There exists $B(A_0, \epsilon) \subset A$ by hypothesis. Then $A_0 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{v}{||v||} \in B(A_0, \epsilon)$. And $\langle A_0 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{v}{||v||}, v \rangle =  \frac{\epsilon}{2}||v|| = \frac{\epsilon}{2}||v|| \neq 0$, therefore yielding a contradiction.
The intuitive fact is the following: **an open set possesses all the dimensions**.

Comment: What's Vect and cl?

Comment: $\text{Vect} := \text{Span}$ and $\text{cl}$ denotes the closure ;)

Comment: And what's that overhead bar?

Comment: The **closure**. Have you ever taken course in topology?

Comment: I'm taking analysis concurrently with topology. I've seen closure in my notes on topology; but it never was denoted as a bar.

Comment: I might need more help than the hint you gave. Is there a more intuitive hint?

Comment: Take a look now.